# Ingress-Nginx regex routing rule with named capture group in path

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, ingress-nginx

I'm creating Kubernetes Ingress resources for an nginx Ingress Controller.  The paths that I'll be using have an ID that I need to extract into a variable that may be in a different location in the path.  E.g.:

```
http://myservice/environment/<someenv>/room/<roomid>
http://myservice/join/<roomid>
```

If I use a non-named capture group in the regex then the first path `roomid` will be `$2` and for the second it'll be `$1`.  Ideally I would be able to use a named capture group to assign it to a specific variable that I can easily use but creating an Ingress with the following path with a named capture group results in an error

```
# ingresses.networking.k8s.io "nginx-consistent" was not valid:
# * spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].path: Invalid value: "/join/(?<roomid>.*)": must be a valid regex
```

Is there a supported way to use named capture groups?

The current configuration doesn't have much interesting in it.  The following is a trimmed down config.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{.Release.Name}}-nginx-route-by-roomid
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-hash-by: "roomid-$roomid"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header ingress-handler nginx-route-by-roomid;
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: {{ .Values.service.serviceName }}
              servicePort: {{ .Values.service.servicePort }}
            path: /api/v1/rooms/(?<roomid>[^/]*)
          - backend:
              serviceName: {{ .Values.service.serviceName }}
              servicePort: {{ .Values.service.servicePort }}
            path: /api/v1/players/([^/]*)/rooms/(?<roomid>[^/]*)
```

Comment: Hello @BenRandall. Could you share your current relevant yaml configs?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor - Updated the question with an example config.

Comment: Hello @BenRandall. Sorry for the late response. Could you also share your k8s version?

Comment: k8s version is `1.18.17-gke.1901`